# Getting text to align at top of large element

Tags: html, css

The problem is that I have an

element that is 78px large.  I need to align text to the right of the `<p>` element and at the top wants to align the text to the center of the element.

is there a way to fix this?

```
<span>
    <p>1</p>
    <span>
        <p>First,</p>
        <p>to the Insured, we promist to pay all valid claims promptly, fairly and efficiently.</p>
    </span>
</span>
```

### css

```
.cont .mid                                    { padding-top:20px; }
.cont .mid span                               { float:left; text-align: left }
.cont .mid span > p                           { float:left; color:#a01d3b; font-size:78.12px; font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; }
.cont .mid span span                          {  }
.cont .mid span span > p                      {  }
.cont .mid span span > p:first-child          { font-size:16.67px; color:#454545; text-align:left; float:left; }
.cont .mid span span > p:last-child           { font-size:9.37px; color:#9a9a9a; text-align:left; float: left }
```

Comment: You don't have any of the classes in your CSS applied to your HTML. Please try creating a fiddle so we can better understand what your issue is.

Comment: You could start by writing [valid html](http://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 0):

```
span{text-align:right}
span > p:first-child{text-align:center}
```

you may need to add that .cont .mid part, but since I see no reference to it, there you go. Either way, the best you can do is to simply use CLASSES, that's what CSS is made for, so you can do it like this:

```
<span>
<p class="centered">1</p>
  <span class="rightalign">
    <p>First,</p>
     <p>to the Insured, we promist to pay all valid claims promptly, fairly and efficiently.</p>
  </span>
 </span>
```

and now you can use .centered and .rightalign anywhere in your site replacing the CSS code I gave you with those classes respectively like

```
.rightalign{text-align:right}
.centered{text-align:center}
```